# making dynamically drawn elements draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got the following code to make an element draggable!

```
$('.item').draggable({
        revert : true,
        zIndex: 1,
        containment: "window"
    });
```

And the code is written inside

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){})
```

These item element is drown dynamically so, when the page loads once, the items are not draggable! but when I refresh the page, it becomes draggable. How can I make the elements draggable the first time page loads.!

Update :

this is the function I use to draw elements dynamically.

```
function populateUIItems(majorGroupId){
    var uiElement = $('.item').first();
    $('#item-list-section').empty();

    ajaxCall("/getItemByMajorGroup?mGroup=Beverage","GET",null,function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i < response.itemModel.length; i++){
            var clone = uiElement.clone();
            clone.children('.item-price').empty();
            clone.children('.item-price').append("<h4>" + response.itemModel[i].sellingPrice + "</h4>");
            clone.children('.item-name').empty();
            clone.children('.item-name').append("<h4>" + response.itemModel[i].description + "</h4>");
            clone.attr('id',response.itemModel[i].itemId);
            clone.css('background-image', "url(../images/item_bg.jpg)");
            $('#item-list-section').append(clone);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you share how the elements are added

Comment: Once the elements are added you need to call `$(addedel).draggable({
        revert : true,
        zIndex: 1,
        containment: "window"
    });` for the added element

Comment: Oh... your idea is nice.! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you need to call the widget for the dynamically added elements.

```
function populateUIItems(majorGroupId){
    var uiElement = $('.item').first();
    $('#item-list-section').empty();

    ajaxCall("/getItemByMajorGroup?mGroup=Beverage","GET",null,function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i < response.itemModel.length; i++){
            var clone = uiElement.clone();
            clone.children('.item-price').empty();
            clone.children('.item-price').append("<h4>" + response.itemModel[i].sellingPrice + "</h4>");
            clone.children('.item-name').empty();
            clone.children('.item-name').append("<h4>" + response.itemModel[i].description + "</h4>");
            clone.attr('id',response.itemModel[i].itemId);
            clone.css('background-image', "url(../images/item_bg.jpg)");
            clone.appendTo('#item-list-section').draggable({
                revert : true,
                zIndex: 1,
                containment: "window"
            });
        }
    });
}
```